# How to concatinate two columns in same array?

Tags: java, algorithm

How to concatinate two columns in same array?

Example:

```
AA AB AC AD

1  0  2  0

2  1  3  3

3  3  0  2

0  2  1  1
```

output:should be like this.

```
AAAB AAAC  AAAD  ABAC  ABAD  ACAD

10   12     10    02    00    20

21   23     23    13    13    33

33   30     32    30    32    02

02   01     01    21    21    11
```

How can I code this in java ?

for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++){

for (int j = 0; j < col.size(); j++) {

for (int k = j + 1; k < col.size(); k++) {

col1.add(val[j]);

col2.add(val[k]);

finalval.add(col1.get(j) + col2.get(k));

}

}

System.out.println("finalval");

}

Comment: This is NOT concatenating two columns, it's concatenating each element to all previous ones. What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should provide more details... I see one 2D array here. And you should also provide some code samples that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[][] input = new String[][] { { "AA", "AB", "AC", "AD" },
               { "1", "0", "2", "0" },
               { "2", "1", "3", "3" }, 
               { "3", "3", "0", "2" }, 
               { "0", "2", "1", "1" } };
    String[][] output = new String[input.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
        output[i] = concat(input[i]);
    print(output);

}

private static String[] concat(String[] strings) {
    int n = strings.length;
    String[] result = new String[(n * (n - 1)) / 2];
    int m = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (i != j)
                result[m++] = strings[i] + strings[j];
    return result;
}

private static void print(String[][] strings) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(strings[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] elements = new String[][] {
            { "AA",  "AB",  "AC",  "AD" },
            { "1",  "0", "2", "0" },
            { "2",  "1",  "3",  "3" },
            { "3", "3", "0", "2" },
            { "0", "2", "1", "1" }
    };

    for (int row = 0; row < elements.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < elements[0].length; col++) {
            for (int x = col + 1; x < elements[0].length; x++) {
                System.out.print(elements[row][col] + elements[row][x] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
AAAB AAAC AAAD ABAC ABAD ACAD 
10 12 10 02 00 20 
21 23 23 13 13 33 
33 30 32 30 32 02 
02 01 01 21 21 11
```